# Difference between Feature Server and Map Server?

Tags: map-service, arcgis-platform, feature-service

I have started to work with Esri maps.

What is the difference between Feature Server and Map Server?

(if possible with examples )

Answer (score 16):

A feature server serves individual layers (aka features) as structured text (xml or json) a  mapserver serves maps as images (png - jpeg - gif)

Answer (score 14):

The ArcGIS documentation actually has pages titled "[What is a feature service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0154/0154000002w8000000.htm)" and "[What is a map service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0154/0154000002m7000000.htm)", the text of which is quoted verbatim here --

Feature Service:

> Feature services allow you to serve features over the Internet and
>   provide the symbology to use when displaying the features. Clients can
>   execute queries to get features and perform edits that can be applied
>   to the server. Feature services provide templates that can be used for
>   an enhanced editing experience on the client. Data from relationship
>   classes and nonspatial tables can also be queried and edited using
>   feature services.

Map Service:

> The map service is the way that you make maps available to the web
>   using ArcGIS. You'll make the map in ArcMap, then publish the map as a
>   service to your ArcGIS Server site. Internet or intranet users can
>   then use the map service in web applications, ArcGIS for Desktop,
>   ArcGIS Online, and other client applications.

It therefore follows that a Map Server is a host that provides map services, and a Feature Server is a host that provides feature services.

It might help to think of a feature service as a special case of a map server's services, since the same basic publishing process is used, and a map service is a prerequisite for a feature service.  It should also be noted that map services *can* provide feature data on request (read-only), unless that capability is disabled during publishing.

Comment: So basically, you'd publish a feature service if you want to edit features and save back to arcserver

Answer (score 4):

As a user, here's how I see the differences between *Feature Services* and *Map Services*:

When I connect to a *Feature Service*, the resulting vector data that appears on my computer screen (via "the cloud") is indistinguishable from a vector layer (i.e. shapefile, geodatabase feature class) stored on my local drive. For example, I can change a *Feature Service's* symbology, open its attribute table and make selections, buffer it, save it to my local drive, join another attribute table to it, the list goes on...

Although a *Map Service* also depicts vector data via the cloud, that data is displayed on screen as a static basemap image (think .jpg).  Accordingly, *Map Services* are limited in what the user can do with them (AFAIK, usage is limited to toggling labels on and off, and clicking with the identify button). The user cannot change a *Map Service's* symbology, nor view an attribute table, nor conduct queries or analyses, nor save to a local drive, nor...

There are nuances and exceptions to my descriptions above.  For example, it's my understanding that a *Feature Service's* provider has the ability to disable editing of the *Feature Service* by the user.

Comment: This is a much more user-centric view of the difference, and therefore more meaningful to somebody who doesn't already understand the difference.  I would add:  A map service renders the feature data on the server into a raster image (or tiles of raster images) and sends those raster images to the client application (eg web browser).  A feature service sends data about the features (and optionally preferred symbology) to the client application (eg web browser) and the client application renders it into an image locally, managing the layers dynamically itself.

Comment: @SonofaBeach Yes, my intent was to answer from a user's point of view.  I'm new to "services" and have been trying to understand the difference.  I've been frustrated by a lack of "plain-speak" descriptions of the differences; for example the ESRI descriptions are, IMHO, word salad.  Strunk and White would be appalled. Additionally, descriptions across the web focus on how to publish services, rather than use them.  Thanks for your comment - I didn't know that services could be viewed on browsers; I've only seen them in QGIS and Arc Desktop.  Much to learn!

Answer (score 3):

I was recently reviewing the difference between the MapServer and FeatureServer, and here are some of my observations,

- MapServer

  - These are suitable for displaying layers as images.
  - Does not provide editing capability.
  - All sublayers are automatically detected by the [LayerList](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html) widget.
  - Symbology and property of each layer can be changed and handled using [sublayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html#sublayers) property.
- FeatureServer

  - These are suitable for displaying images as features
  - Provides editing capability to the client application
  - All sublayers need to be grouped using the [GroupLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GroupLayer.html) class and then added to the [LayerList](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html) widget.
  - Properties and symbology can also be edited individually but NOT with sublayer property.

As for the capability of each server, you can head out to this link for a quick comparison. [Map service properties -> Capabilities](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/publish-map-services/setting-map-service-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_36B90DE5C96D430FBC9F4E7B338ACC9D)

But the more important thing to note here is how they are retrieved at the client side. Below is the comparison of the same layer with both capabilities turned on and the network list is sort by time. We can see that MapServer layer takes longer time to retrieve as compared to the FeatureServer

[image: MapServer FeatureServer comparison]

Answer (score 0):

I go this way to differentiate as most of the time I use Non-ESRI Software like QGIS, OpenLayers etc. ArcGIS Feature Service and Map Service in general both have same capabilities in terms of consuming the data, querying using REST APIs.

The differences ONLY when used in ESRI products (ArcGIS Pro, ESRI JS API library etc) as explained by others users comments and answers.

Comment: A feature service can be used to edit data from non-ESRI applications, using the REST API.  This is often how data sync between GIS and asset systems is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

General speaking,

- FeatureServer allow you editing via rest api
- MapServer does not allow editing